# Can a SharePoint list item have it's Targeted Audience calculated or otherwise automatically specified?

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I want to show targeted (filtered) content from a list to users.  I already have a column in the list that basically has the Target Audience value.  This field is a multi-choice column (checkbox input) which I prefer over the current input field for Targeted Audiences.

To get audience filtering to work I unfortunately need to have the Targeted Audience field filled out for every list item.  My current plan is to use a simple SharePoint designer workflow to set the Targeted Audiences field based on my other field, but I'm wondering if there is a better way.  Am I just looking at this wrong?

Note that I know audiences can also be used to hide/show web parts, but that is not something I am interested in.

Comment: Do you want different users to have different views of the same list?  Or, is the targetting set for the whole list?

Comment: I want different users (really groups of users - audiences) to have different views (filters) of the same list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe Target Audiences can be set up as a calculated field, in which case your options are workflow or a list item event receiver.

To set the audience field value, you can use [`AudienceManager.GetAudienceIDsAsText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.audience.audiencemanager.getaudienceidsastext.aspx); Gary Lapointe has a [post with example usage](http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2008/04/programmatically-setting-web-part.html).

Comment: Thanks - this looks like the best choice available to me.

Answer (score 4):

You could try and give this a whirl...

```
SPField audienceField = null;

try
{
    audienceField = list.Fields[Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.FieldId.AudienceTargeting]
}
catch
{}

if(audienceField != null)
{
try
{
    Audience siteAudience;
    ServerContext context = ServerContext.GetContext(site);
    AudienceManager audManager = new AudienceManager(context);
    foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
    {
      string audienceName = item["fakeAudienceField"]; //should be the audience name created in SSP
      siteAudience = audManager.GetAudience(audienceName);
      Guid id = siteAudience.AudienceID;
      item["Target Audiences"] = id.ToString()+";;;;";
      item.Update();
    }
}
catch
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a webpart to display the content of the list and use Audiences on the webpart sounds a solution easier to manage...

Comment: Are you saying to use a custom web part?  That could certainly work, but not the answer I was hoping to hear.  My hope is that I just don't understand audiences enough and there is some simple setting that I am missing.

Comment: I see Audiencies just to mark on object if it is visible or not. Combined with permission settings can narrow what is displayed to different user groups...

I have asked in another topic of good implementations of a hiding and showing menuitems dependent on the status of an item/member of audiences